# Validation "blank" or "empty" in cakephp Form

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I just created a form in cakephp and I would like to do a validation for one of the field.

The form will only be submitted if this particular field is left empty.

Here's a my particular field

```
<?php echo
    $this->Form->input('MyForm.fieldA', array(
      'type'        => 'text',
      'label'       => '',
      'class'       => 'span3 detector-form',
    ))
?>
```

And my validation code:

```
public $validate = array(
    'fieldA' => array(
        'rule'      => 'blank',             
        'on'        => 'submit',
        'message'   => 'Failed authorize',
        'last'      => true
    ),
);
```

P/s. I tried using

```
public $validate = array(
    'fieldA' => array(
        'rule'      => 'blank',             
        'on'        => 'create',
        'message'   => 'Failed authorize',
        'last'      => true
    ),
);
```

But the 'create' sounds like only worked when the field is created.So I changed to 'submit' for a testing purpose.
I tried to use rule''=> 'Empty' as well but the validation doesn't work. Or is there any other alternative rules that I can use to reach this goal?

Comment: Try to post your Model, and your complete view (filename, and at least `$this->Form->create()` tag). By the way, you should just use `update` or `create` on key `on` http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#on

Comment: If you want the validation to work on create and update, you should leave the option `'on' => null` or ommit the option `on` (because its default is null)